# Use paste0 to create multiple object names with a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, paste

I would like to create multiple object names with a for loop. I have tried the following which fails horribly:

```
somevar_1 = c(1,2,3)
somevar_2 = c(4,5,6)
somevar_3 = c(7,8,9)
for (n in length(1:3)) {
x <- as.name(paste0("somevar_",[i]))
x[2]
}
```

The desired result is `x` being `somevar_1`, `somevar_2`, `somevar_3` for the respective iterations, and `x[2]` being `2`, `5` and `8` respectively.

How should I do this?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do `as.character(c(somevar_1,somevar_2,somevar_3))`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment.. But what Aron below does is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
somevar_1 = c(1,2,3)
somevar_2 = c(4,5,6)
somevar_3 = c(7,8,9)
for (n in 1:3) {
  x <- get(paste0("somevar_", n))
  print(x[2])
}
```

**Result**

```
[1] 2
[1] 5
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget` to get all the required objects in a list and use `sapply` to subset 2nd element from each of them.

```
sapply(mget(paste0("somevar_", 1:3)), `[`, 2)

#somevar_1 somevar_2 somevar_3 
#        2         5         8
```

Comment: This functional approach is the better answer.

Comment: Thank you Ronak. The idea was to use the for-loop to update one list based on another list. Something like: `for (n in 2) {
  x <- get(paste0("somelist_", n))
  listofNLD[[n]] <- x[['NLD']]
}` Could you tell me how that works with your code?

Comment: @Tom Probably something like `Map(function(x, y) {listofNLD[[x]] <- y[["NLD"]];listofNLD}, 1:3, mget(paste0("somevar_", 1:3)))`